# How to assign a value to state and use setState in ReactJs with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have played around with state and setState in a few test projects in the past but now I'm working on a new project and when I do `this.state = new ProductDto("some product name");` i get an error "`Cannot convert type ProductDto to type {(): any;(): any}`".

and when i also do `this.setState(product);` I get an error:

`Supplied parameter do not match any signature of call target because no overload accepts one parameters.Candidates are:`
`K<any>() => (void)`
`K<any>() => (void)`

my code looks like this.

```
class ProductDto {
  constructor(name?: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  name: string;
}

class Product extends React.Component<any, ProductDto> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = new ProductDto("some product name");
  }
  handleChangeProduct(product: ProductDto) {
    this.setState(product);
  }
  ...
}
```

I am using `typescript: "^2.2.1", @types/react: "^15.0.13" and react": "^15.4.2"`

and the definitions for setState looks like this in the index.d.ts file

`setState<K extends keyof S>(f: (prevState: S, props: P) => Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;`

`setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;`.

Any help on how to get these working will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Using classes as state is atypical and possibly problematic with how React handles state... instead just use an interface and an object literal. You could maybe use `{ product: ProductDto }` as your state.

Comment: Provide a plain object to `this.state`.

Comment: @Aaron I have also tried using an interface and an object literal but it didnt help.

Comment: @Mudi What do you mean "it didnt help"? It should work.

Comment: @Aaron I think it has to do with the new typings version. i just added an older version(v0.14) of the typings and it works. it's definition is `setState(state: S, callback?: () => any): void;`. also there is something about setState being stricter in the new react typings version on the definitelyTyped site but i'm not sure how to make it work still.

Comment: @Mudi `setState()` doesn't seem compatible with using a class type directly as state, but I was suggesting to use an interface and an object literal as state. That should work. See Deividas' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React state must be an object. `setState` accepts an object or a function which returns an object as first parameter. That being said, the state object can contain classes (which are functions).

In you case you can set the state as follows

```
this.state = { product: new ProductDto("some product name") };
```

and then update it

```
this.setState({ product });
```

You can read more about react state here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html